# How do I export test results from Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: continuous-integration, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have a couple of projects in Visual Studio Team Services: one for server side code, and another for the javascript-rich UI.  I'm now trying to set up a dashboard for the team to see things like build status and test coverage, and can't figure out how to get the data out of Visual Studio Team Services, or if such a thing is possible.

I've tried creating a Service Hook for the project, and attaching a new WebHook subscriber.  This then posts a JSON object to my dashboard containing all information that it will let me send.  Here is an example from the "test" button when setting up the WebHook:

```
{
    "subscriptionId": "2d0988c2-e1a6-45b7-ada0-cf3355beeb9f",
    "notificationId": 4,
    "id": "4a5d99d6-1c75-4e53-91b9-ee80057d4ce3",
    "eventType": "build.complete",
    "publisherId": "tfs",
    "message": {
        "text": "Build ConsumerAddressModule_20150407.2 succeeded",
        "html": "Build <a href=\"https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/web/build.aspx?pcguid=5023c10b-bef3-41c3-bf53-686c4e34ee9e&amp;builduri=vstfs%3a%2f%2f%2fBuild%2fBuild%2f3\">ConsumerAddressModule_20150407.2</a> succeeded",
        "markdown": "Build [ConsumerAddressModule_20150407.2](https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/web/build.aspx?pcguid=5023c10b-bef3-41c3-bf53-686c4e34ee9e&builduri=vstfs%3a%2f%2f%2fBuild%2fBuild%2f3) succeeded"
    },
    "detailedMessage": {
        "text": "Build ConsumerAddressModule_20150407.2 succeeded",
        "html": "Build <a href=\"https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/web/build.aspx?pcguid=5023c10b-bef3-41c3-bf53-686c4e34ee9e&amp;builduri=vstfs%3a%2f%2f%2fBuild%2fBuild%2f3\">ConsumerAddressModule_20150407.2</a> succeeded",
        "markdown": "Build [ConsumerAddressModule_20150407.2](https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/web/build.aspx?pcguid=5023c10b-bef3-41c3-bf53-686c4e34ee9e&builduri=vstfs%3a%2f%2f%2fBuild%2fBuild%2f3) succeeded"
    },
    "resource": {
        "uri": "vstfs:///Build/Build/2",
        "id": 2,
        "buildNumber": "ConsumerAddressModule_20150407.1",
        "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/71777fbc-1cf2-4bd1-9540-128c1c71f766/_apis/build/Builds/2",
        "startTime": "2015-04-07T18:04:06.83Z",
        "finishTime": "2015-04-07T18:06:10.69Z",
        "reason": "manual",
        "status": "succeeded",
        "dropLocation": "#/3/drop",
        "drop": {
            "location": "#/3/drop",
            "type": "container",
            "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/resources/Containers/3/drop",
            "downloadUrl": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/resources/Containers/3/drop?api-version=1.0&$format=zip&downloadFileName=ConsumerAddressModule_20150407.1_drop"
        },
        "log": {
            "type": "container",
            "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/resources/Containers/3/logs",
            "downloadUrl": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/_apis/resources/Containers/3/logs?api-version=1.0&$format=zip&downloadFileName=ConsumerAddressModule_20150407.1_logs"
        },
        "sourceGetVersion": "LG:refs/heads/master:600c52d2d5b655caa111abfd863e5a9bd304bb0e",
        "lastChangedBy": {
            "id": "d6245f20-2af8-44f4-9451-8107cb2767db",
            "displayName": "Normal Paulk",
            "uniqueName": "fabrikamfiber16@hotmail.com",
            "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/_apis/Identities/d6245f20-2af8-44f4-9451-8107cb2767db",
            "imageUrl": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_api/_common/identityImage?id=d6245f20-2af8-44f4-9451-8107cb2767db"
        },
        "retainIndefinitely": false,
        "hasDiagnostics": true,
        "definition": {
            "batchSize": 1,
            "triggerType": "none",
            "definitionType": "xaml",
            "id": 2,
            "name": "ConsumerAddressModule",
            "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/71777fbc-1cf2-4bd1-9540-128c1c71f766/_apis/build/Definitions/2"
        },
        "queue": {
            "queueType": "buildController",
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Hosted Build Controller",
            "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/build/Queues/4"
        },
        "requests": [{
            "id": 1,
            "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/71777fbc-1cf2-4bd1-9540-128c1c71f766/_apis/build/Requests/1",
            "requestedFor": {
                "id": "d6245f20-2af8-44f4-9451-8107cb2767db",
                "displayName": "Normal Paulk",
                "uniqueName": "fabrikamfiber16@hotmail.com",
                "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/_apis/Identities/d6245f20-2af8-44f4-9451-8107cb2767db",
                "imageUrl": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_api/_common/identityImage?id=d6245f20-2af8-44f4-9451-8107cb2767db"
            }
        }]
    },
    "resourceVersion": "1.0",
    "resourceContainers": {
        "collection": {
            "id": "c12d0eb8-e382-443b-9f9c-c52cba5014c2"
        },
        "account": {
            "id": "f844ec47-a9db-4511-8281-8b63f4eaf94e"
        },
        "project": {
            "id": "be9b3917-87e6-42a4-a549-2bc06a7a878f"
        }
    },
    "createdDate": "2016-04-27T14:45:20.8150184Z"
}
```

There are a few useful fields here in the `resource` property, such as `status`, `startTime` and `finishTime` (from which I can work out how long the build took).  But there is nothing about the tests.

In my UI project, the tests and coverage both have a publish step that saves the results to an XML file on the build server.  So at the minute the only way I can see to share more detailed information with the dashboard is to write a custom script that reads those XML files and POSTs them to a REST API as the final step of the build.

If anyone knows of a cleaner way to get VSTS to do what I need, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

The information you want is stored in "TestRuns". When you create a service hook for "Build Completed" event, it only send the information included in the build. So there is no test information included. However you can write a script to get the related test runs information with the "builduri" information in Service Hooks via [VSTS Rest Api](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/test/runs#Getalistoftestruns).
[image]